# Domino nvapplet.jar Security Exception

Tags: java, jar, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a long standing domino application that uses embedded views to display data.  This application has been moved from a server 2003, 32 bit, domino 8.5 environment to a new server 2008 R2 64 bit domino 8.5.3 FP6 environment.

I have everything up and working as before with the exception of embedded views.  They are giving a SecurityException "Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://*.com/domjava/nvapplet.jar".

I have confirmed that the actionbar.jar, editor.jar, nvapplet.jar, and outline.jar are the current version on the server.  I have even replaced them with the version from the IBM download (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21662233).

I can get this to work by displaying the view as HTML instead of Java Applet, but I don't understand what the issue is with the java version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this situation may have been a little unique, but I will post it here for future reference in case anyone else runs into this.  The server was a fresh build of windows and domino all the way up to 8.5.3 FP6.  The FP6 installer date stamps the jars in question with the install date of the system.  So in my case I had people come to the site, download the jar with a file date newer than 1/17/2014, which is the date of the files IBM put in the fix mentioned above.  Those files are a simple flat copy so they always maintain the 1/17/2014 date.  Anyway, any user that came and picked up the newer date files 3/1/2014 for example would keep those files or rev date in their local java machine cache and ignore the 1/17/2014 file I had replaced them with, thus they continued to show the problem.  Only by manually clearing their cache from the java were they able to pick up the 1/17/2014 file and no longer have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There were major security changes to Java in relation to applets. You can download the latest applets here.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21662233

You may need to clear your browser cache if it still persists after that.

**[update]** The question now mentions that you installed Fixpack 6, installed the Jars then uninstalled Fixpack 6.

When you uninstall a fix pack, it reverts the files it touches back to what they were before the fix pack was installed. Although I have no details on it, it is quite likely that the updated security applets were also added to fix pack 6 (as it's the last fix pack for R8.5.3).

So during the uninstall the applets look the same as FP6 and it reverts them.

To solve this, after the revert you would need to drop in the updated applets again.

If the issue still persists at this point, you need to open the Java Console on your browser and update your question with the logs it generates (as it pertains to the error).

Comment: I have installed FP6, put the jars in you mentioned above, rolled back fp6 and I get the same error under all 3 conditions.    You link is exactly the "IBM download" I was referring to in my original question.   I edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: @Simon Please, double check everything. We have upgraded our servers yesterday and the error has gone. Or provide more information...

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth did you mean to talk to "Erik"?

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Yup, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Actually from what I was told via IBM FP 6, does not include the fixed .jars.  That was my main problem assuming it did.